# Link a variable to image name in windows forms

Tags: c#

I would like to set a picture box with an image but have an integer link it together.

The images in the resource are named *picture_1, picture_2, and picture_3*

This is what I'm trying to do, however, I get an error:

```
imageNumber = 1;
image_position[0, 1].Image = Properties.Resources.picture_ + imageNumber;
```

I am trying to set the picture box to *picture_1* but get this:

Error   CS0117  'Resources' does not contain a definition for 'picture_'

Comment: Is there a mistake here `image_position[0, 1].Image = Properties.Resources.picture_ + imageNumber`? What does `Properties.Resources.picture_` contain? Is it a string variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the [`ResourceManager.GetObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getobject) method. It accepts string names:

```
image_position[0, 1].Image =
    (Image) Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("picture_" + imageNumber);
```